# Qt focus handling for virtual keyboard operated only by UDLR buttons

Tags: qt, keyboard, focus, virtual

I have a data entry screen on a Qt/Embedded device that only has up/down/left/right/select buttons. The screen looks like a calculator with a QLineEdit on top and a set of QPushButtons for the numbers. The UDLR buttons move focus around the QPushButtons and select appends the button's number to the QLineEdit. This works great. However, since the QLineEdit doesn't have focus, the text entry cursor doesn't blink. The QLineEdit just doesn't look like it's the recipient of the virtual keyboard button presses and that's not good.

The other Qt virtual keyboard implementations that I've seen don't need their keyboard buttons to gain focus since they are touch or mouse operated. Therefore, the QLineEdit can retain focus the entire time. That's not an option here. The best the I've seen so far is manual generation of focus events to trick the QLineEdit into thinking that it has focus when the user is really navigating around the virtual keyboard. I am hoping that there is a more elegant solution or maybe a different way to structure the screen's implementation that avoids this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like you don't need the true editing capabilities of `QLineEdit`, replace it with a `QLabel`. You can nest it inside a frame to make it look like an edit box. Then you can simulate a blinking cursor using a `QTimer` that doesn't need focus to work.

Start the timer with a 500ms interval and in the timer slot, insert or remove a '|' character like this:

```
void MainWindow::slot_timeout()
{
    QString labelText = label->text();    
    if(labelText.right(1) == "|")
    {
        labelText = labelText.left(labelText.size()-1);
    }
    else
    {
        labelText += "|";
    }    
    label->setText(labelText);
}
```

When your select button is pressed, insert the appropriate character at the front of the string so that the blinking cursor stays on the right end.

```
void MainWindow::slot_selectClick()
{
    QString labelText = label->text();
    labelText.prepend("x");
    label->setText(labelText);
}
```

It might be enough to achieve the effect you are looking for.

Comment: This may be a good way for me to go. It feels better than manually sending focus events to `QLineEdit` even though it's a little more code. I'm coming to the conclusion that Qt doesn't have a way to specify a subfocus or dual focus like what I would need to use the existing widgets, and if it did, it would be complicated. Your solution has the advantage of being really easy to understand.

Comment: I'm following up on this post in case any one else comes across it with the same issue. I ended up using `QLineEdit` and manually sending focus events. Two reasons: the `QLabel` solution was tricky to make the cursor alignment look right especially when the entry box filled, and internationalization support for right to left languages was so much easier with `QLineEdit`.

Comment: Those are important considerations. It would be good if you could post that as an answer, especially if there is some helpful code. It's perfectly acceptable to "accept" your own answer here :)